# Does the PageObject require the @DefaultUrl tag despite using the setDefaultBaseUrl method in constructor?

Tags: serenity-bdd

I am trying to create an abstract PageObject that I can dynamically assign the default url so the code can be shared across all stages of development.

```
    package com.company.serenity.product.common.ui;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

    import net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject;
    import net.thucydides.core.util.EnvironmentVariables;

    abstract public class AbstractPageObject extends PageObject {

      protected AbstractPageObject() {
        super();
        super.setDefaultBaseUrl(getDefaultBaseUrl());
        init();
      }

      protected AbstractPageObject(final WebDriver driver, Predicate<? super PageObject> callback) {
        super(driver, callback);
        this.setDefaultBaseUrl(getDefaultBaseUrl());
        init();
      }

      public AbstractPageObject(final WebDriver driver, final int ajaxTimeout) {
        super(driver, ajaxTimeout);
        this.setDefaultBaseUrl(getDefaultBaseUrl());
        init();
      }

      public AbstractPageObject(final WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.setDefaultBaseUrl(getDefaultBaseUrl());
        init();
      }

      public AbstractPageObject(final WebDriver driver,
          final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables) {
        super(driver, environmentVariables);
        this.setDefaultBaseUrl(getDefaultBaseUrl());
        init();
      }

      // return the default url (from final static property)
      abstract protected String getDefaultBaseUrl();

      // any other initiation stuff that should happen with the constructor
      abstract protected void init();

    }
```

I am currently using:
serenity.version: 2.0.29
serenity.maven.version: 2.0.29

The result:

```
TEST FAILED: Should be able to login
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST FAILED AT STEP Administrator opens the Sudo site
[main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - Undefined default URL for page object AbstractPageObject
```

Thanks so much in advance. Appreciate everyone's precious time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do it dymnamically, why don't you use the configuration options. If you create a serenity.conf file and add the following snippet:

```html
environments {
  default {
    webdriver.base.url = "http://mywebsite.local"
  }
  dev {
    webdriver.base.url = "http://mywebsite.local"
  }
  uat {
    webdriver.base.url = "https://mywebsite-uat.mysite.com/"
  }
  prod {
    webdriver.base.url = "http://mywebsite.mysite.com"
  }
}
```

Then when running the tests run them with the environment switch -Denvironment=dev for example.